# angular 2 route to 404 page when route param is invalid

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular

Say I have an route with a param like this (in Angular 2): `/user1/products/:id`, which could have child routes like `/user1/products/3/reviews`.

When I navigate to `/user1/products/-1`, I check with my server and if the product doesn't exist, I want to render a 404 page without affecting the browser history.

Using `router.navigate(['/404'])` or `router.navigateByUrl('/404')` doesn't seem to work because it adds both `/user1/products/-1` and`/404` to the browser history.

Meaning when I press the **Back** button in the browser, I go back to `/user1/products/-1` which is immediately redirected to `/404` and I'm essentially stuck at `/404`.

In ExpressJS, we would do something like `next()` to pass the request to our 404 handler. Is there a client-side equivalent in Angular 2?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227194/handling-404-with-angular2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**

In the new Router V3 you can use guards as explained in https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication

**Original**

I think you should use [@CanActivate()](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) to do the check. If you forward in `@CanActivate()` the invalid URL shouldn't be added to the history (not tried)

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112 for how to use DI in `@CanActivate()`

Comment: Thanks for the link, I injected the router into `@CanActivate()`, but it looks like `router.navigate` pushes to the history when you navigate to an invalid page directly through the browser's address bar, causing the **Back** button functionality to break.

Comment: I see. Another idea would be to use a custom `<router-outlet>` haven't tried that myself. I think I posted some example code recently (not mine) hete on SO

Comment: I asked the angular guys. We can use `router.navigateByUrl(url, true)` in the `@CanActivate()` hook to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this is already implemented, just not well-documented.

According to the docs:
`router.navigateByUrl(url: string, _skipLocationChange?: boolean) : Promise<any>`

Has a parameter _skipLocationChange that will not modify the history.
These will do the trick:

`router.navigateByUrl('/404', true);`
`router.navigateByInstruction(router.generate(['/404']), true);`

Answer (score 4):

As of Angular 2 final this is the solution:

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('/404', { skipLocationChange: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Its really interesting question, perhaps you should report it as feature request. I would be nice to have access to router instruction inside `loader` callback of RouteDefinition.

You could try to emulate validation adding default route `/**` and using `regex` parameter of RouteDefinition to match only positive numbers.