# Angular2: how to redirect if API returns an error?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

In my service, I want to describe a behavior when user is being redirected if not authorized.

```
export class MessagesService {
    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    private _usersUrl = '/users.json';  // URL to web api


    getUsers() {
        return this.http.get(this._usersUrl)
            .map(res => <User[]> res.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError (error: Response) {

        if (error.status == 401) {
            // How do I tell Angular to navigate LoginComponent from here?
        } else {
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Is it even possible?
- Is that a good practice?

  - If yes, how do I perform that?
  - If no, how else can I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599523/angular-2-route-to-404-page-when-route-param-is-invalid/36609006#36609006

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it doesn't answer on my question about using router in service

Comment: Not sure why. If you inject the router `constructor (private http: Http, private router:Router) {}` you should be able to use it. See also the link below the question.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined`

Comment: Can you create a Plunker?

Comment: Regarding the TypeError, I ran into the same thing. To fix, use an arrow function in the catch: `.catch((err) => {return this.handleError(err)});` so handleError has access to `this.router`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861413/angular-2-how-to-handle-4xx-errors-with-redirect-in-observable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My approach was to create my own request service and have an interceptor function which wraps the actual request to handle 401 and 403 etc.

Have included it below if you want to have a look at it.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core"
import {Subscription, Observable} from "rxjs"
import {TokenModel} from "../../models/token.model"
import {TokenService} from "../authentication/token.service"
import {Http, Headers, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod} from "@angular/http"
import {Router} from "@angular/router"

@Injectable()
export class RequestService
{
    private baseUrl: string;
    private subscription: Subscription;
    private token: TokenModel;

    constructor(public tokenService: TokenService,
                public http: Http,
                public router: Router)
    {
        this.baseUrl = `${process.env.API_URL}/example`;
        this.subscription = this.tokenService.token$.subscribe(token => this.token = token);
    }

    get(path: string, params?: Object, withCredentials?: boolean): Observable<any>
    {
        this.checkAuthorised();

        const url: string = this.baseUrl + path;
        const headers: Headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        });

        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(`user_session=${this.token.token}`);

        for (let param in params) searchParams.set(param, params[param]);

        const options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            url: url,
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            headers: headers,
            search: searchParams,
            withCredentials: withCredentials
        });

        const request = new Request(options);

        return this.makeRequest(request);
    }

    post(path: string, body?: Object, params?: Object, useDataProperty?: boolean, withCredentials?: boolean): Observable<any>
    {
        this.checkAuthorised();

        const url: string = this.baseUrl + path;

        const headers: Headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });

        const data = JSON.stringify(useDataProperty ? {data: body} : body);

        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(`user_session=${this.token.token}`);

        for (let param in params) searchParams.set(param, params[param]);

        const options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            url: url,
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            headers: headers,
            body: data,
            search: searchParams,
            withCredentials: withCredentials
        });

        const request = new Request(options);

        return this.makeRequest(request);
    }

    makeRequest(request: Request)
    {
        return this.intercept(this.http.request(request).map(res => res.json()));
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<any>)
    {
        return observable.catch(err =>
        {

            if (err.status === 401)
            {
                return this.unauthorised();

            } else if (err.status === 403)
            {
                return this.forbidden();
            } else
            {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });
    }

    unauthorised(): Observable<any>
    {
        this.tokenService.clear();
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return Observable.empty();
    }

    forbidden(): Observable<any>
    {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return Observable.empty();
    }

    checkAuthorised(): void
    {
        if (!this.token.token.length)
        {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't think that posting of a link is a good idea. Your gist can be removed one day. I think it's better to post your code here.

Answer (score 1):

One direction we've been approaching this on our team is by implementing an API client class. This API client wraps the original Http service.

The idea is that since the Http service produces observables you can easily extend its behavior by adding operators like `map`, `flatMap` and `catch` operators to the original observable produced by the Http service.

I think you will find this example a useful starting point to fix the problem you're having.

```
import { ApiRequestOptions } from './api-request-options.service';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/zip';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ApiClient {
    // PLease note, the API request options service is a helper that we introduced
    // to generate absolute URLs based on settings in the client.
    // I did not include it here for brevity.
    constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http, private requestOptions: ApiRequestOptions) {

    }

    get<TResponse>(path: string, queryStringParams?: any): Observable<TResponse> {
        let self = this;

        return Observable.zip(
            this.requestOptions.absoluteUrlFor(path, queryStringParams),
            this.requestOptions.authorizedRequestOptions()
        ).flatMap(requestOpts => {
            let [url, options] = requestOpts;
            return self.http.get(url, options);
        }).catch(response => {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                self.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }

            return response;
        }).map((response: Response) => <TResponse>response.json());
    }

    post<TResponse>(path: string, body: any): Observable<TResponse> {
        let self = this;

        return Observable.zip(
            this.requestOptions.absoluteUrlFor(path),
            this.requestOptions.authorizedRequestOptions()
        ).flatMap(requestOpts => {
            let [url, options] = requestOpts;
            return self.http.post(url, body, options);
        }).catch(response => {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                self.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }

            return response;
        }).map((response: Response) => <TResponse>response.json());
    }

    put<TResponse>(path: string, body: any): Observable<TResponse> {
        let self = this;

        return Observable.zip(
            this.requestOptions.absoluteUrlFor(path),
            this.requestOptions.authorizedRequestOptions()
        ).flatMap(requestOpts => {
            let [url, options] = requestOpts;
            return self.http.put(url, body, options);
        }).catch(response => {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                self.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }

            return response;
        }).map((response: Response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return <TResponse>response.json();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    delete(path: string): Observable<Response> {
        let self = this;

        return Observable.zip(
            this.requestOptions.absoluteUrlFor(path),
            this.requestOptions.authorizedRequestOptions()
        ).flatMap(requestOpts => {
            let [url, options] = requestOpts;
            return self.http.delete(url, options);
        }).catch(response => {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                self.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }

            return response;
        });
    }
}
```