# Angular 2. How to handle 4xx errors with redirect in Observable?

Tags: error-handling, angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I have a service that calls an api

```
getItems(itemId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, headers)
        .map(this.extractDataSingle)
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

If the server responds with an 4xx the `catch` part is called.
Here is my `handleError` method.

```
private handleError = (error: any) => {
    //Here I want to redirect to login.
}
```

I want to redirect to the `login` page. 
Simply typing `this._router.navigate(['Login']);` does not work since I have to return a `Observable`. 
Returning an empty Observable `return Observable.empty;` does not work, too, because then I get an error with my subscribers: `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`.

How can I achieve that I redirect the user to the login page? Of course I can change my subscribers to catch the error and redirect via my subscribers. But I think it is better to handle the error in my service.

I'm also open for completely different solutions of how to handle 4xx errors.

EDIT:
Thanks to @GüntherZöschbauer. The `return Observable.of([]);` is exactly what I needed. 
However, be aware of `this`. In order to have access to the `router` in the  `handleError` method use `bind(this)` in `.catch(this.handleError.bind(this))`

```
getItems(itemId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, headers)
        .map(this.extractDataSingle)
        .catch(this.handleError.bind(this))
}
```

Otherwise you don't have access to your `router`.

Comment: `empty` is a function and you need to actually call it to get an actual observable: `return Observable.empty();`

Comment: You can also use arrow functions `.catch((err) => this.handleError(err))`

Comment: I found arrow functions to be a much cleaner approach to be able to use `this`, compared to bind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this does what you want:

```
private handleError = (error: any) => {
   this._router.navigate(['Login']);
   return Observable.of([]);
}
```

Comment: I'm doing just this, I also tried `return Observable.empty()` but I still get `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`. I'm not sure if this has to do with the component being destroyed???

Comment: @Joao This doesn't sound related. I guess it's better to create a new question with the code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks. posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213494/angular-2-redirect-in-http-rxjs-catch-callback-causes-typeerror-cannot-read-pro