# Angular 2 redirect in http/rxjs catch callback causes TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

When redirecting from the rxjs catch function I get the error: `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

Here's the relevant part of `contactService`:

```
getContacts () {
  ...
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, options)
                  .map(this.extractData, this)
                  .catch(err => {
                    this.handleError(err)
                  })
}
...
handleError (error) {
  if(error.status === 401){
    //the redirect works great, except, when added, I get the exception error
    this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    return Observable.of([])//this is my attempt based on link below
  }
  else{
    // In a real world app, we might send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error'
    console.error(errMsg) // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg)
  }
}
```

In the consuming component:

```
...
ngOnInit(){
  this.getContacts()
}

getContacts(){
  this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(
    (contacts) => { this.contacts = contacts },
    (error) => { this.errorMessage = error }
  )
}
```

This question ([Angular 2. How to handle 4xx errors with redirect in Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861413/angular-2-how-to-handle-4xx-errors-with-redirect-in-observable)) would suggest that I'm doing this right, but maybe I'm missing something in my component?

Comment: What do you return when `error.status !== 401`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've updated the question so you can see. I'm basically just doing what the tutorial suggests (for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `return` missing

```
return this.handleError(err)
```

Comment: :D happens to the best of us