# Angular2 Navigating to a path upon HTTP 401 error

Tags: http, angular, error-handling, routes

I am using a service in Angular2 that issues HTTP requests to a RESTful API server. I need to catch the 401 error and redirect the user to /login page. For some reason the router.nagivate(['/login']) does not get executed in the code below. Note that I have followed the instructions in this answer [Angular 2 redirect in http/rxjs catch callback causes TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213494/angular-2-redirect-in-http-rxjs-catch-callback-causes-typeerror-cannot-read-pro), but my code doesn't redirect.

```
search(term: string): Observable<[]> {
return this.http
  .get(this.userListUrl+'User?name='+term')
  .map((r: Response) => r.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

```
  private handleError(error: any): Observable<any>{
if(error.status == 401) {
  console.error('An error occurred', error.status);
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  return Observable.of([]);
} else {
  let errMsg = error.statusText || 'Server error';
  console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}}

constructor(private http: Http, private router:Router) {}
```

Edit: Updated handlerError code.

Comment: Does the error get logged to console from your `handleError` function?

Comment: Yes it does. And it's 401.

Answer (score 0):

In ui-router-ng2 (`import { UIRouter } from 'ui-router-ng2';`), you can navigate programmatically by injecting router: UIRouter and calling [the go method](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#go): **`router.stateService.go('somestate')`**

**EXEMPLE**:

in your `app.routing.ts` :

```
export const ROUTES: any = [
  {url: '/login',             name: 'Login',      component: LoginComponent}
]
```

Then you function should be :

```
if(error.status == 401) {
  this.router.stateService.go('Login');
}
```

Where the `router` is

```
private router:      UIRouter;
```

in your `Constructor`.

Comment: Thanks @53l3m. I am hoping there is a native Angular2 way of doing this, especially since the user in the link I mentioned was successful in routing using the same code as I have.

Comment: it doesn't require a thing, just instead of `import { Router}` you'll `import { UIRouter } from 'ui-router-ng2'; `
` , is that a big deal ?

Comment: I'm sorry @53l3m, I don't mean to offend you , but I'm looking to resolve this without adding new modules to my code  and by fixing what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Good luck dude :)